# What exactly does setEditing() do in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem` under `viewDidLoad()`, and it is said that I have to implement `setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool)` as well. It seems like every editing functionality works great without setEditing function. What does it do??

```swift
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
    tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
  }

    override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: true)
        tableView.setEditing(tableView.isEditing, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> and it is said that I have to implement setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) as well

Then "it is said" incorrectly.

The built-in `editButtonItem` of a UITableViewController automatically calls the table view's `setEditing` for you; there is no need, therefore, to duplicate that functionality. To be more precise:

1. The built-in `editButtonItem` of a UIViewController does two things:

   - It calls the UIViewController's `setEditing(_:animated:)` when tapped.
   - It tracks the UIViewController's `isEditing` property, and changes its own title accordingly (Edit or Done).
2. Moreover, UITableViewController's implementation of `setEditing(_:animated:)` calls `setEditing(_:animated:)` on its table view.

Thus, you *would* need to do that last step if this were not a UITableViewController. But it is, so you don't.

Comment: Dear Matt, 
thank you for your feedback. If that's the case, when do people use `setEditing()` along with `editButtonItem`?

Comment: When this is not a UITableViewController, or when they do not use the built-in `editButtonItem`.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt! Could you provide an example when you use setEditing? Maybe those without built-in `editButtonItem`?

Comment: I've discussed it here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_table_view_editing